# Unusual object definition

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon this, to my eyes, strange object declaration.

```
var config = {};
{ 
  config.foo = 'foo';
  config.bar = 'bar';
};
```

It works, though I would have guessed it wouldn't.

Confused I open up the console in Chrome DevTools, and enter:

```
var a = {};
// => undefined
```

Nothing strange so far. But then I enter:

```
{ a.b = 'b'; }
// => Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Ok, hmm ... wasn't this supposed to work? Another try, without separate evaluations of the statements:

```
var a = {}; {a.b = 'b'};
// => "b"
```

Hmm, no SyntaxError thrown. And if I evaluate a, I can see it is defined as I intended.

```
a;
// => Object {b: "b"}
```

What is happening? I've tried to google it, but I don't know what to search for, and I lack some kind of knowledge to figure out what is happening. Can someone please explain it?

Comment: It's just a pointless block used for style. It's not part of the declaration or initializer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In this case. Blocks do actually have meaning when you use [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) or [block-scoped variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)!

Comment: Chrome thinks you're trying to make an object, so it puts parenthesis around the `{a.b = 'b'}`. When you put a statement before the `{a.b = 'b'}` it realized that you aren't entering an expression, you're entering a program, and treated it like an actual [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). Note that Firefox won't automatically put parenthesis around what Chrome had seen as an expression.

Comment: @towerofnix, Yes! That must be it! So Chrome actually interprets it as `var a = {}; ({ a.b = 'b' });`? If you add an answer I will mark it as accepted!

Comment: @towerofnix: No, in *this case*, there is no point to the block whatsoever. **If** it were using ES2015 and block-scoped variables (there's nothing label-able here), that would be different, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on to what has previously been said..

In JavaScript, this is an object literal:

```
{x: 3}
```

And this is a block:

```
{
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}
```

Any statement can go inside of a block.

The trouble is, `{x: 3}` will normally be interpreted as a block, on its own.

To make it an object literal as far as JavaScript is concerned, you have to surround it in parenthesis:

```
({x: 3})
```

That's what Chrome DevTools does whenever it sees that your input is an object literal that isn't surrounded. It'll make `{x: 3}` into `({x: 3})`, `{y: 15, z: 'kar'}` into `({y: 15, z: 'kar'})`, and so on.

The trouble is, it'll also do this for blocks. It turns `{x = y}` into `({x = y})`, which is of course a syntax error. JavaScript thinks you're giving it an object literal, so it doesn't expect a statement.

However, DevTools completely ignores the rule of turning un-parenthesized object literals into parenthesized object literals if you have a statement before the object literal. So this works:

```
console.log('Bananas!'); {x = y}
```

And the statement doesn't *really* need to be a statement. There actually just needs to be a semicolon before the block:

```
;{x = y}
```

It's just a weird quirk of Chrome DevTools. It's supposed to help people new to coding with JavaScript (and object literals), but it can be slightly confusing to people that *are* experienced!

Answer (score 5):

In the code,

```
var config = {};
{ 
  config.foo = 'foo';
  config.bar = 'bar';
};
```

The code inside second `{` and `}` is just statements grouped in a block. **The block is used to group multiple statements** and is valid syntax so, no error is thrown.

The code is equivalent to

```
var config = {};
config.foo = 'foo';
config.bar = 'bar';
```

The code inside the block is executed and the `config` object is

```
{foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
```

after the execution of the block.

Instead of using the above syntax, it's **better to use object literal syntax** to define an object.

```
var config = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar
};
```

---

Same with the code

```
var a = {}; {a.b = 'b'};
```

Which is equivalent to

```
var a = {};
a.b = 'b';
```

and can be written as

```
var a = {
    b: 'b';
};
```

From [**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

> A **block statement** (or **compound statement** in other languages) is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets.

---

> `{ a.b = 'b'; }` throws *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .*

This will throw error if variable `a` is not declared.

Comment: Well the thing I have a trouble to understand, is that `a` is defined in my example. And why is not a ReferenceError thrown if a isn't defined? If I do another try `var z = {}; {x.q = 'q'};` a ReferenceError is thrown: 'x is not defined'. So I think something else is happening. I can not understand why it matters if I evaluate several identical statements in the repl one by one or in a "batch".

Comment: `{ config.foo = 'foo'; config.bar = 'bar'; };` is the same as `config.foo = 'foo'; config.bar = 'bar';`. Assignments will not work if `config` is not a _defined_ object.

Comment: @JohanJonasson: It matters because of the state of the parser, though in example in that comment you'll get the error about `x` either way. Your `var a = {};` says `undefined` in the console because that's just what it says for `var` statements; you can ignore that. If you do `var a;` then `a = {};` it shows the result of the assignment (an object). `{x.q = 'q'}` fails with `x is undefined` because it's a block of code, not an obj initializer, because when the parser is expecting a *statement*, `{` starts a block; it only starts an obj initializer when the parser is expecting an *expression*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for your explanation, but this is not what I was wondering about. I understand these things perfectly clear. I might have been a bit unclear, and maybe a screenshot of my interaction with the console would have explained the issue in a better way than I did in my question.